# How to make XunitExceptions more meaningful?

Tags: c#, tdd, xunit

I have a bunch of instances and properties they I would like to validate using XUnit.

```
myInstance.SomeProperty1.Should().HaveCount(2);
myInstance.SomeProperty2.Should().HaveCount(2);
[...]
myInstance.SomePropertyN.Should().HaveCount(2);
```

When this asserts fail, they throw the following kind of exceptions

```
Xunit.Sdk.XunitException
Expected collection to contain 2 item(s), but found 0.
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.XUnit2TestFramework.Throw(String message)
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionScope.FailWith(String message, Object[] args)
   at FluentAssertions.Collections.SelfReferencingCollectionAssertions`2.HaveCount(Int32 expected, String because, Object[] becauseArgs)
   at [...]
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xunit.Sdk.TestInvoker`1.<>c__DisplayClass48_1.<<InvokeTestMethodAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xunit.Sdk.ExecutionTimer.<AggregateAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xunit.Sdk.ExceptionAggregator.<RunAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
```

So far so good. But how can I make the exception more meaningful? I would like to see the name of the property on which the assert failed.

The thing is, this are quite big objects and spinning up the test always takes quite some time. Knowing on which property the tests failed would speed up my testing process. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could just pass the "because" argument, which are available for all these assertions in FluentAssertions. Or do you need a more generic solution?

Comment: Did you consider using a non-fluent assertions? i.e standard native xUnit asserts? They might output the properties you need. Or does it need to be written using fluent Asserts?

Comment: You can have own test for every property, where name of the test will quickly provide you required information. You don't even need to read description of failed test ;)